# STM32F4 Discovery board hal blink not blinking

Tags: stm32, gpio, stm32f4discovery, hal

I just started to play with HAL on stm32f4 discovery board.
The most basic blink doesn't work, any hint on that matter would be helpful?
Code itself compiles without any problems.

I was testing STM32CubeMX and used pre-generated main file frome it.
There is nothing advanced inside which could be cause of problem.

I am using CooCox CoIDE development enviroment for it.

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14,GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(2000);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_Delay(2000);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

  __PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5);

  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

}

/** Configure pins as
        * Analog
        * Input
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
     PC3   ------> I2S2_SD
     PA4   ------> I2S3_WS
     PA5   ------> SPI1_SCK
     PA6   ------> SPI1_MISO
     PA7   ------> SPI1_MOSI
     PB10   ------> I2S2_CK
     PC7   ------> I2S3_MCK
     PA9   ------> USB_OTG_FS_VBUS
     PA10   ------> USB_OTG_FS_ID
     PA11   ------> USB_OTG_FS_DM
     PA12   ------> USB_OTG_FS_DP
     PC10   ------> I2S3_CK
     PC12   ------> I2S3_SD
     PB6   ------> I2C1_SCL
     PB9   ------> I2C1_SDA
*/
void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PE3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_SPI3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA5 PA6 PA7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB2 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB10 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD12 PD13 PD14 PD15
                           PD4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15
                          |GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC7 PC10 PC12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_SPI3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA10 PA11 PA12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF10_OTG_FS;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PD5 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB6 PB9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PE1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
*/

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: You have lot of peripherals defined, please for begin try remove all unnecessary parts and start on greenfield and/or try debug it. From my point of view STM32CumeMX promise more than it can. But what I try, basic code generated with cube was working OK.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing obvious wrong with the code you have posted - most of it is generated by stm32cubemx, right?

Try checking inside of the stm32f4xx_it.c file - are you calling HAL_IncTick(); within the SysTick interrupt? Without that, the HAL_Delay function won't work ...

Also, have you tried single stepping through your code in debug mode to see what is happening? At the very least that might tell you if you are hanging anywhere.

If none of the above helps, then I would recommend trashing the MX_GPIO_Init function and writing your own that just initialises the GPIO pin you want to toggle.

This is my main problem with stm32cubmx - the output is overly complicated! The clock configuration stuff is nice, but I don't want that in main.c - in a separate file would be OK (ish)...

Alex

Comment: I suggest to debug the code and investigate in the registers of clock and in the registers of IO port. I Agree with Alex... check the HAL_IncTick()